# Any alternatives to Qt on certified aviation platforms?

Tags: qt, vxworks, rtos

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934559/qt-alternative) posted asking in general about alternatives to Qt.  Well, I am specifically interested any certified alternatives to Qt.   Specifically, if there are any Qt alternatives that have flown or are flying on certified aviation stacks. (so just knowing Qt alternative is not sufficient)

I am pursuing this question, because Digia has been unresponsive to requests for information regarding the commercial Qt, which is supposed to run on WindRiver/VxWork and Integrity (Green Hills), and Qnx (I think).  I specifically asked about their pursuit of Qt on flight certified DO-178 environments and received zero reply and received similar response (as you might imagine) from Nokia.

Given that level of feedback, and as a risk reduction effort, I am pursing alternatives.

Thanks for any feedback and insights.

Comment: I have no idea why you were downvoted.  The most common alternative to Qt (on the desktop) is wxWidgets, I have no idea if this will run on an aviation platform - you'll have to do your own research for that.  However, if these aviation platforms are mature, do they not have their UI equivalents?

Comment: DO you need a GUI that runs on vxworks/QNX or does the gui have to be certified aswell? Vxworks and integrety have a dials+button glass-cockpit type gui(which I assume is certified) but they can also run X so should handle any Unix GUI

Comment: RTOS needs to be certified, GUI will be partitioned and certain partions certified.  Thus, (over simplifying) the certified GUI will need to run on a certified OS, so the GUI needs to be developed in a language that is certifiable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the OS being certified have you looked at this product?

[GL Studio](http://www.disti.com/Products/glstudio/)

From their product page looks like they are involved in aerospace, medical, military applications. May want to inquire if they have any certifications.

Comment: Thanks for this tip. I will plan to follow up with them.